# Using jtds-1.3.1.jar to connect android app to Microsoft Azure SQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, azure

I have tried all solutions offered from every post related to TSL version. I have no idea what went wrong.
I still got the same error:

> E/SQL Exception:: Reason: Login failed due to client TLS version being less than minimal TLS version allowed by the server.

Things that I have tried:

0. configure Azure SQL server database min TSL version 1.0 > 1.1> 1.2
1. using jtds-1.3.1.jar
2. using mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8.jar
3. connect to Microsoft SSMS (successful)
4. test query at SSMS (successful): "USE userdata;\n" +
   "SELECT * FROM user;"

   ```
   public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

    con = sqlserverconn(); // connect to userdata database

    String query = "USE userdata;\n" +
            "SELECT * FROM user;";

    try {
         //initialize SSLContext field
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sc.init(null, null, null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        Statement statement = con.createStatement(); // create statements
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query); // execute query

        //get data from returned query
        if(result.next()){
            id = result.getInt("Id");
            deviceid = result.getString("deviceId");
            username = result.getString("userName");
            password = result.getString("password");
            email = result.getString("email");

            //set text data
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    login_id.setText(String.valueOf(id));
                    login_deviceid.setText(deviceid);
                    login_username.setText(username);
                    login_password.setText(password);
                    login_email.setText(email);
                }
            });
        }
        result.close();
        statement.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("SQL Exception: ",e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return "";
    }
    }

      @SuppressLint("newApi")
     public Connection sqlserverconn(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        //database connection string here
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://userdata-dataserver.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=userdata;user=userdata@userdata-dataserver;password=xxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
        connection =DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    }
   catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("SQL Exception: ",e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Class Not Found: ",e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return connection;
    }
   ```

Comment: I would avoid jtds, it's a bit outdated, try microsoft jdbc, and post the code in the quesiton

Comment: Aside... you shouldn't have Android and iOS devices using the TDS protocol to connect to SQL Servers across the open internet. TDS was designed 30 years ago for LAN applications and, because it's so chatty, performs horribly as latency increases across the open internet - and especially in mobile WAN environments where time-sharing and packet encapsulation happens at many layers. Consider instead implementing a web service (e.g.: a RESTful API) in front of your SQL Server and use HTTPS for data transfer instead - it's more efficient and more secure to boot.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for rich reply. Would you mind to share a link on how to use RESTful API to connect Azure SQL server? I am pretty new on this RESTful API thing :( assume that I know nothing.